# accessing a methods property from another method

Tags: javascript

i want to access properties of a class method inside another method but i am getting NaN result. Isn't it possible to access the values of this.x and this.y from calSum()? Thanks

```js
class Calc{
  constructor(){}
  
  num(){
    this.x = 5;
    this.y = 4;
  }
  
  calSum(){
    this.sum = this.x + this.y;
    console.log(this.sum);
  }
}

const s = new Calc();
s.calSum();
```

Comment: Bind `this.num` to `this` in the constructor

Comment: You'd want to call `s.num()` to initialise your instance before `s.calSum()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox That has nothing to do with it. Unless you meant "*Call `this.num()` in the constructor*"?

Comment: @Bergi I didn't. sad face 

Comment: i figured out the issue, yes the answer to this example is calling  s.num() before s.calSum(). the problem i had with my original code was that the first method was an async method, so when i tried to use a property in the async method in another method, the method ran before the async method finished running so the value of the property return undefined

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `this.x` and `this.y` are not initialised in `Calc` constructor.

This results in `this.x` and `this.y` to be `undefined`.

`undefined + undefined` produces `NaN`.

I've updated `constructor` with initial values of zero for both x and y:

```
class Calc{
  constructor(){
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
  }
  
  num(){
    this.x = 5;
    this.y = 4;
  }
  
  calSum(){
    this.sum = this.x + this.y;
    console.log(this.sum);
  }
}

const s = new Calc();
s.calSum();
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/baezl16/pen/XWKxdJN. am trying to achieve something like this, he didn't initialize this.ingredents in the constructor